# wpf ribbon complete tutorial

Tags: wpf, ribbon

How to use ribbon control mainly in quick access toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some samples there too

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4

Comment: how i can use this sample? i've downloaded the sample and install

Comment: See: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Ribbon for WPF\MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples.zip`. There are some solutions inside.